# Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Tarefas'. Only one identity column per table is allowed Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

how are you? I'm facing some troubles with sqlite database in a education course.
I have a MVC C# project, using DBContext. I have created one migration, but when I run the command fails with this message in title.
I've tried:
recreate the database (not worked)
check identity on database( one primary key exists => Id)
check connection with database in Program.cs (ok)
Check my model (I think it's correct)

Here is my model for my table :

namespace ProjetoPIM7.Models
{

```
[Table("Tarefas")]
public class Tarefa
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Descrição:")]        
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Data planejada:")]     
    public DateTime DataTarefa { get; set; }       
    public DateTime DataEncerramento { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that you recreated the database table? The error indicates that there already exists a table with a identifier column in it.

Comment: This could also be that when re-creating the database that the migration code in the solution did not get deleted/removed beforehand.

Comment: I have recreated all entire project, making againa the methods, the DBContext, but now I'm dealing with empty returns.

Comment: My database: database.sqlite, is in root directory of project, and declared in Web.Config as Default Connection String.                                                                                                  I'll make an aswer to show you how my database is, and models and EFContext Class.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Do you have data in the database?

Comment: Yes, I have some data in tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Entity Framework, I have Web.config declared with my SQLite DB as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=database.sqlite;Version=3"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My EFContext Class created:

public class EFContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext{
public EFContext() : base("Default") { }

```
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }
```

}
My TarefasController make reference to EFContext to get info as ahead:

```
public class TarefasController : Controller
{

    private EFContext context = new EFContext();
    // GET: Tarefas
    public ActionResult Tarefa()
    {
        return View(context.Tarefas.OrderBy(c => c.Descricao).ToList());
    }
```

Then, my view associates with specified Model but gets empty return on table:

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.Tarefa>
<tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem
                            => item.Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem
                            => item.Descricao)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem
                           => item.DataTarefa)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

I've picked only the necessáry parts to show you friends. I'm thankful for any help.